# Minikube on Docker shows high CPU utilization every 10 seconds

Tags: docker, kubernetes, airflow, cpu-usage, minikube

For development I am using the following setup:

- 8 core 16 thread CPU w/ 64 GiB RAM
- Arch Linux
- Docker
- Minikube on Docker (4 CPUs 16 GiB memory)

This single node kubernetes cluster houses

- 1 RabbitMQ pod deployed via the bitnami helm chart
- 1 Airflow instance deployed via the apache helm chart (2.7.x)
- 3 mounts from the host system into the cluster via minikube mount (uid 50.000, gid 0) (e.g. DAG folder for development without the need for gitsync)
- ingress and metrics plugins for minikube are active
- airflow image has been extended with a driver for legacy oracle DBs and a custom operator for rabbitmq but otherwise vanilla

Memory utilization is at around 50% on the machine, or below. HDD and SSD space is plenty. I/O on network and drives doesn't show anything suspicious.

The issue is, that, when the cluster is not paused, it fully loads my CPU every ~10 seconds for 2-3 seconds (that is *all* cores) in a way that the whole system slows down and youtube music playback begins getting choppy.

Constraining resources via `minikube --cpus X` has no effect. Constraining resources via `docker --cpus X` caps the load but spreads it over time to the effect, that the machine is chugging constantly.

HTOP shows that the culprit is dockerd taking over 1000% CPU%, at first glance, while the Kubernetes/Minikube Dashboard shows *no* unexpected activity or high CPU use. The command showing up with high CPU intensity is (multiple instances, likely 1 per thread, that is 16):

```
/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --default-ulimit=nofile=1048576:1048576 --tlsverify --tlscacert /etc/docker/ca.pem --tlscert /etc/docker/server.pem --tlskey /etc/docker/server-key.pem --label provider=docker --insecure-registry 10.96.0.0/12
```

I have experimented with different setups, moved my docker-directory on a dedicated SSD, which seemed to alleviate the problem somewhat.

The spikes in CPU usage seem to be somewhat correlated with read activity on the SSD partition, but  this is clearly not the root cause, even though it seemed so when the directory still resided on an HDD partition.

The pattern does not exist in "normal" docker usage and surfaces exclusively when using minikube. Removing the RabbitMQ helm chart does not change anything. Neither do the docker logs (journalctl -u docker) indicate that anything is wrong. So my best guess is that some interaction of airflow, minikube and docker induces high CPU usage.

I read through regular airflow-tasks which might influence the performance, but none of them as a frequency similar to the pattern I'm observing and the pods' CPU usage doesn't show anything unexpected.

After some more experimenting I am pretty certain that Minikube and its interaction with Docker is the problem's source. The CPU usage pattern surfaces when starting Minikube and *before* deploying anything via helm. It gets worse with time and with more things deployed on Minikube though.

So my question would be whether anybody more experienced in docker/minikube has an idea what's going on. Thx!

Comment: `HTOP shows that the culprit is dockerd taking over 1000% CPU%` Do the [docker daemon logs](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/logs/) log something at the time that there's very high CPU usage? That could be a clue into what it's doing.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Unfortunately, the docker logs don't show anything but a failure to access the DNS from a few weeks ago. Since my problem persists since before that, I fear that's a dead end.

Comment: Have you tried another kubernetes distro like k3s or kind? When the Problem still exists with those it's not a minikube problem

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I thought about it, but I didn't have the time to do it yet, as I have a hard deadline for the project that is based on this. This effectively focuses all my work on just getting the software itself to run; this problem 'just' being a development nuisance.
After fiddling around with the whole setup, I am now sure, that it is a Minikube problem, as the CPU usage pattern is visible right after starting minikube and before doing anything else.This is good, as it tells me that this is not likely to resurface as a problem when actually deploying it to AWS EKS.